# xlwt set style making error: More than 4094 XFs (styles)

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I use Xlwt for writing an excel file. it's cells has some style (color, alignment ,borders ,  ... )

when i use XFStyle and set borders and other attr of style, in some cases it make error:
More than 4094 XFs (styles)

why?
what should i do with this error?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/python-excel/xxetAMesyEg.

Comment: I've seen this before, the solution that mentioned in this link did not help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I read and trace functions and methods that calls during execution.

i find solution:

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook(style_compression=2)
```

use : style_compression=2

its work!

Comment: NOTE that if you faced that problem without using many styles, you are most probably did something wrong. Do not call `easyxf()` to describe one style repeatedly in cycles, for example.

Comment: Correct fix should be to reuse styles. I don't belive you have 4094 different styles... I upvoted answer below, cause it is more valid.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry Nazarov : prize of the best comment

Answer (score 9):

Upon encountering the same problem in the LOOP I have extracted the description of format from the loop and it continued smoothly:

this did not work:

```
for ... :
    ws. row(row_index).write(col_index, value, easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour yellow; align: wrap 1'))
```

but this does:

```
ostyle = easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour yellow; align: wrap 1')

for .... :
    ws.row(row_index).write(col_index, value,ostyle)
```

Answer (score 4):

So, for future generations, whoever you are searching for answer, you do something wrong in your code.

Basically, what happens with your code is that you generated over 4094 different styles instances (Important, not different styles, it is enough if you create new instances of style).

In our case we had something like:

```
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    workbook.write(i, 0, row, currency_formatter(row))
```

Where currency formatter was created new style for each row.

What we had to do, was to cache style per each currency if style was the same.

So, correct fix is not to create so many styles!

Cheers, Mike.