# xlwt ValueError: more than 4094 XFs (styles) [while using pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6, xlwt, valueerror

I'm trying to use pandas to write and later retrieve a lot of data to an excel file. After writing about 4,000 lines, it throws a ValueError relating to styles (example code and trace below).

Code:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xls', style_compression = 2) as writer:
    row = 0
    while 1: #running it until I stop it during testing
        data = get_that_sweet_data()
        df = pd.DataFrame(data) #makes a DataFrame object with two rows
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet1, startrow = row)
        row += 3
```

Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scribe.py", line 96, in <module>
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet1, startrow = row)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1545, in to_excel
    engine=engine)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 649, in write
    freeze_panes=freeze_panes)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1518, in write_cells
    val, style)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1088, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 231, in write
    style_index = self.__parent_wb.add_style(style)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 324, in add_style
    return self.__styles.add(style)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Style.py", line 92, in add
    return self._add_style(style)[1]
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Style.py", line 151, in _add_style
    raise ValueError("More than 4094 XFs (styles)")
ValueError: More than 4094 XFs (styles)
```

The error seems to lie in xlwt, specifically with creating a new style every time a new line is written, and then passing the limit of styles. There are two related posts: [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130516/xlwt-set-style-making-error-more-than-4094-xfs-styles) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569287/xlwt-code-results-in-valueerror-more-than-4094-xfs-styles) dealing with the same error. I tried passing in style_compression = 2 (answer to post 1) but it didn't help.

Part of my problem is that I can't find the proper documentation involved here. Pandas describes the to_excel() function, but it doesn't take style arguments. I can't find pandas documentation on what ExcelWriter is, but I guess it is a function from xlwt? It took in the style_compression variable without throwing an error. The xlwt documentation doesn't seem very good; I can't find the relevant material, or what the pandas ExcelWriter maps to in xlwt. One answer seems to be to set a single style and then pass that in to the write function each time it is called, but since I don't understand what function is being used here I'm not sure what to set where and where/how it could be passed in.

Any help (including just pointing me to the right reference material) would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out how to control the formatting appropriately to avoid this error, but I did find an easy workaround.

use

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx') as writer:
```

instead of

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xls') as writer: # just changed the file type
```

I test wrote in over a million DataFrames within a loop and it didn't throw any errors.